# SQL Counting Calls from other tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Having trouble counting from a separate table. I'm only getting how many callers are making calls rather than each individual count for every call.
I have went in and checked that most callers make multiple calls but i'm not sure how to show this.
I'm looking for which Company has >18 calls.

Tables are:

Customer

```
Company_ref
Company_name
Contact_id
Address_1
Address_2
```

Caller

```
Caller_id
Company_ref
First_name
Last_name
```

Issue

```
Call_ref
Caller_id
Call_date
Detail
```

Query:

```
SELECT Company_name, Count(Call_ref)
from Customer JOIN Issue on (Contact_id = Caller_id)
Group by Company_name
```

and example of the outcome is

Affright Retail 5
Askew Inc.  5
Askew Shipping  6
Bai Services    2
Cell Group  5
Comfiture Traders   5

which is only counting how many callers rather than how many calls made

Comment: update your question add a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Please tag either mysql or oracle if you're not using both DBs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work (MS SQL-Server):

```
select a.Company_ref, count(c.Call_ref) as Calls from caller a
join Issue b on (a.Caller_id = b.Caller_id)
join Customer c on (a.Company_ref = c.Company_ref)
group by a.Company_ref
```

adding a Where clause to determine companies with 18 or more calls:

```
select * from (
    select a.Company_ref, count(c.Call_ref) as Calls from caller a
    join Issue b on (a.Caller_id = b.Caller_id)
    join Customer c on (a.Company_ref = c.Company_ref)
    group by a.Company_ref ) result
where Calls > 18
```

Comment: This is exactly what i needed, is there any chance you can run me through how you done it?
Thanks again!

Comment: @TerribleProgrammer I am (inner join by default) joining the tables you have listed. Customer table join with Caller table by using Company_ref column, then you connect Caller table with Issue table by using Caller_id. Now all tables are connected by relationship. Now you use an aggregate function to count the number of calls and group it by the company. Once you get the result, you can use it as a sub-query to query all company with calls > 18. I would recommend you to learn more about relationships/joins and aggregate functions. That will assist you in creating queries such as the above.

Answer (score 0):

`CallerID` refers to `Caller` table not `Customer` table

```
  SELECT Y.Company_name, Count(I.Call_ref)
  FROM Issue I
  JOIN Customer C
    ON I.Caller_id = C.Caller_id
  JOIN Company Y
    ON C.Company_ref = Y.Company_ref
  Group by Company_name
```